# How to detect double tap with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm trying to detect a double tap with RxSwift

Without RxSwift I would something like this:

```
private func setupFakePanView() {
    let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

    singleTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapped))
    doubleTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.doubleTapped))

    someView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)
    someView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)
}

@objc private func tapped() {
    // Do something
}

@objc private func doubleTapped() {
    // Do something else
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve the same with RxSwift, RxCocoa and [RxGesture](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxGesture)? I've tried the following but of course it doesn't work:

```
someView.rx
    .tapGesture(numberOfTouchesRequired: 1, numberOfTapsRequired: 1)
    .when(.recognized)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // Do something
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)

someView.rx
    .tapGesture(numberOfTouchesRequired: 1, numberOfTapsRequired: 2)
    .when(.recognized)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // Do something else
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Is there way to let the first tapGesture know the second has to fail?

Comment: You can set the delegate for the single tap gesture and then use `shouldRequireFailureOf` method

Comment: Are you using a library for those extra operators? If so, then what is it? If not, then what is their implementation?

Comment: Setting the delegate won't work, how would you implement `shouldRequireFailureOf` in that case. You would need the other gesture as well right? @KishanBhatiya

Comment: Yes, oh should have added that: RxGesture. @DanielT.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxGesture/issues/46

Comment: Yes that works, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found 2 solutions to solve this problem!

#### A. Using a custom `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)

let singleTap = someView.rx
    .gesture(singleTapGesture)
    .when(.recognized)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // Do something
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)


let doubleTap = someView.rx
    .gesture(doubleTapGesture)
    .when(.recognized)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // Do something else
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

or..

#### B. Using a custom `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Thanks [Kishan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9728533/kishan-bhatiya) for suggesting [Jegnux's answer](http://%20https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxGesture/issues/43#issuecomment-289122644)!

1 - Set a custom delegate for the single tap gesture...

```
someView.rx
    .tapGesture(
        numberOfTouchesRequired: 1,
        numberOfTapsRequired: 1,
        configuration: { [weak self] gesture, delegate in
            gesture.delegate = self
        }
    )
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // Do something
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)

// double tap same as before
```

2 - Implement `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRequireFailureOf:)`

```
extension MyController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let gesture = otherGestureRecognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer, gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 {
             return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Both solutions work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work:

```
tap
    .flatMapFirst {
        tap
        .takeUntil(tap.startWith(()).debounce(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance))
        .startWith(())
        .reduce(0) { acc, _ in acc + 1 }
    }
    .map { min($0, 2) }
```

Just use a single gesture recognizer (whose event is called `tap`) that emits instantly when a tap occurs. The code above the `map` generalizes this problem to output the number of successive taps within a certain period of each other (300 ms) in this case. The map is simply to ensure that only a `1` or a `2` comes out. Then do whatever conditional logic with it that you please. I tested it with a `UIButton` successfully.

Comment: Interesting use of all these operators!

Comment: @Tieme Dank je wel!

Comment: `tap` needs to be a shared observable for this to work